# ToastContentBuilder could not be found

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, .net-core, uwp

I'm trying to use toast notifications in my Windows app, and I'm using the following code...

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddText("Hello");
```

But I'm getting the following error...

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToastContentBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/7.0.0-preview4)!

In Visual Studio's solution explorer, right click your project, click "Manage NuGet Packages", search for "uwp notifications" and install the **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications** package.

Then, IntelliSense should suggest adding the following using statement...

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
```

After that, everything should be working!

Comment: This answer does not work for me in Unity. Once the package in installed in Visual Studio, it will not show an error but the Unity editor will show the above error. Once unity is restarted, both the Unity Editor and Visual Studios will show the error until the package in uninstalled and reinstalled.